# V8 (node c++ addon)

Tags: c++, linux, node.js

Нужно проверить наличие пользователя в системе, используя js, node.js и node c++ аддон. Передачу имени пользователя на сервер я сделал. Но при написании аддона на с++ столкнулся с проблемой, что c++ для node.js сильно отличается от обычного чистого с++.

Теперь сам вопрос.
Скажите, пожалуйста, какие `namespace` нужны для получения списка учетных записей в системе (Сама задача аддона - проверить наличие пользователя в ubuntu)? Или где можно почитать именно на эту тему (сайты со списком всех неймспейсов на английском мне вряд ли помогут, не зная какой именно искать).

Еще помог бы пример по данной задаче.

Comment: Язык c++ остается языком c++, даже когда вы пишете аддоны для node.js, никаких отличий нет.

Comment: Остается то остается, конечно, но отличие кода на с++ аддона для node.js есть. В этом и сложность. Где в чистом С++ приложении нужно написать строку кода, здесь в несколько раз больше чаще всего.

Comment: Очень интересно, напишите для примера, такую строку "чистого" приложения, которую приходится несколькими строками заменять для аддона node.js.

Comment: int a = 1; и HandleScope handle_scope;Local<Integer> a = Integer::New(1); Подойдет?

Comment: Это не равнозначный код. Первый вариант - встроенный тип, второй - пользовательский. К тому же оба варианта - чистый c++.

Comment: Vladimir, посоветуйте тогда как подключить библиотеки для работы с файлами в такой addon.cc файл, пожалуйста

Comment: Как обычно, например с помощью `std::fstream` (`#inlcude <fstream>`)

Comment: Так, с файлами спасибо, но есть еще вопрос: void check(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {} Как получить строковое значение args[0] для вставки в путь для получения путь к файлу. Скажи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, функции для получения списка пользователей в стандартной библиотеке нет. Поэтому придётся руками читать `/etc/passwd` и забирать из каждой строки имена пользователей.

Comment: Кхм. Ну если уж кто-то минусует, то покажите пожалуйста в  `unistd.h` функции для достижения желаемого результата

Answer (score 0):

Для доступа к списку пользователей особых namespace не требуется:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct passwd *pw;

    setpwent();
    pw = getpwnam(argv[1]); // программа требует аргумент - имя пользователя
    if(pw) {
        std::cout << pw->pw_name << " uid=" << pw->pw_uid << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }else {
        std::cerr << "Пользователь " << argv[1] << " системе не известен\n";
        return 1;
    }
    endpwent();
}
```

Это конечно не плагин, простая программа на C++. После проверки, что код работает, можно использовать основную часть функции, заменив строку поиска на строку из аргументов функции плагина.

```
...
String::AsciiValue name(args[0]->ToString());
setpwent();
pw = getpwnam(*name);
...
endpwent();
```